# Is there a way to dynamically assign a CSS class to an MVC4 Html.Encode entry?

Tags: c#, css, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple field in one of my views that shows a sum for one of my columns using this code:

```
<p class="points-total" >@Html.Encode(ViewData["pointsTotal"])</p>
```

This is my controller code regarding `pointsTotal`:

```
pointsTotal = occurrences.Sum(o => o.Points);
ViewData["pointsTotal"] = pointsTotal.ToString();
```

I would like to assign a different class to this line based on the value of `pointsTotal`. For example if the total is over 50 points I'd like to assign it to class `points-total-fifty`.

I know I can do this on other HTML helpers like DisplayFor by doing this:

```
<p class="@(item.Total > 50 ? "points-total-fifty" : 
         "points-total")">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)</p>
```

Is there a way to do the same thing with the Html.Encode helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the code you put for your second example will work also with the `Html.Encode` helper as you are styling the `<p>` element. One way to do it for example:

```
@{
    string cssClass = "points-total";
    int? total = ViewData["pointsTotal"] as int?;

    if (total.HasValue && total > 50)
    {
        cssClass = "points-total-fifty";
    }
}
<p class="@cssClass" >@Html.Encode(ViewData["pointsTotal"])</p>
```

Comment: For some reason I had to use `Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["pointsTotal"]);` to cast the string instead, but then it worked great. Thanks!